# Is it possible to disable proxy in one Entity Framework query?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

Is it possible to disable proxy in Entity Framework in one dedicated query? I don't want to impact on rest of solution.

I want to turn off proxy objects and get 'native' Goal and GoalProgressItem. How to get non-proxy objects.

```
var goalWithProgressItemsPairs = _dbContext.GoalProgressItems
    .Include(p => p.Goal)
    .Where(p => p.Date >= range.From && p.Date <= range.To)
    .Select(p =>
        new
        {
            Goal = p.Goal,
            ProgressItem = p
        }
    )
    .ToList();
```

Comment: What do you mean by `native` and `proxy`? What do you want to occur that your above query is (or is not) doing?

Comment: @Igor In my DbContext I have defined DbSet<Goal> Goals. I mean "Goal" as 'native' type, defined by me.
Query return proxy type which inherits from Goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to set the 'ProxyCreationEnabled' property of the Configuration property of your _dbContext before your call ?
Something like

```
_dbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
// Your query
_dbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
```